# DoDragDrop Hang on UI Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, drag-and-drop, telerik

I have a C# .Net 4.0 project that is a Winforms App which we are in the middle of converting to a WPF app. I am having an issue with the WPF half. My view is laid out like this when the bug occurs:

[image: View Layout]

We use [Telerik RadDocking](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/raddocking/overview2) to handle the docking.  When I resize the Floating WPF child when it is over the Docked WPF child, suddenly Telerik thinks that I dragged one of the Detail controls. This triggers an event on the Winforms hosting side of the app which calls `System.Windowns.Forms.UserControl.DoDragDrop()`. Normally, dragging one of these controls works fine, but for some reason, this hangs the UI thread on the call to `DoDragDrop()`.

I realize that there is likely some bug in the Telerik code which causes the drag operation to erroneously fire. However, what I really want to know is the possible reasons why `DoDragDrop()` would ever hang when called on the "Main UI Thread".  Looking at my other threads, none of them seem to be deadlocked while trying to handle a drag operation.

Comment: Are there any any events `OnDragStart` or `OnDragDrop`? There is a situation where calling a `.Result` of an async method (which returns a `Task`) instead of using `await` would make the UI thread to deadlock.

Comment: I do have a few controls that implement `OnDragDrop`, but I am not seeing them in the callstacks of any of the threads when the hang occurs. Do you have a link to more information on this `Task.Result` issue?

Comment: Sure, [here you are](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).